# Adding class to child img element, after it is injected?

Tags: jquery

My question is about the code on this page... http://www.pinspired.com/art/3d/

I have a thumbnail image. When you click on it, the image enlarges and the following code is injected...

```
<div class="slide current">
    <img src="http://image.jpg">
</div>
```

I am using a plugin for this. The code in the plugin that injects this code is...

```
$.each( elements,  function(){
    $('#swipebox-slider').append('<div class="slide"></div>');
});
```

I would like to add a class to the IMG element, but cannot seem to do this with jQuery. I have tried the following...

```
$('.slide').find('img').addClass('newclass');
```

...however this does not seem to work, possibly due to the fact that the .slide class is not originally in the DOM.

Is there anyway I can add a class to the img tag?

Even doing something radical like this does not apply the class...

```
$('body').find('img').addClass('newClass');
```

Comment: `$('.slide img')` seems to be the correct selector, if you omit the `find()`.

Comment: Sorry David, that was a typo, I have corrected the question.

Comment: No codehorse that does not work. #swipebox-slider also gets injected. Have a look at the source code before you click the thumbnail and you will see what is originally there.

Answer (score 1):

Both will work:

```
$('.slide img').addClass('newclass');
```

or

```
$('.slide').find('img').addClass('newclass');
```

As @David Thomas said: An img is an empty element, and cannot contain any other elements

Comment: Sorry that was my fault, it was a typo when writing the question, I have corrected the question. The problem seems to be that .slide is not in the DOM initially

Comment: It doesnt matter, if you call this line after it is inserted, it must work

Comment: No unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#swipebox-slider').find('img').addClass('newClass');
```